# sql related in importation and creation of tables

Tags: sql, types, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Am importing my sql from the htdocs folder in xampp but this table aint runing due to some error which i can't seem to identify

```
CREATE TABLE `product_list` (
  `id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `image_path` text DEFAULT NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `delete_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I tried commenting the line of status and delete flag and the table was created successfully but they are important in my project thus can't be removed.

This is the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
> `status` boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
> `delete_flag` boolean NO...' at line 8

Comment: What is your intent with `int(30)`? The maximum value you can store in an [`int unsigned`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/int/) column is 4,294,967,295. You shouldn't store prices in [FLOAT/DOUBLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/floating-point-accuracy/) columns, use [DECIMAL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/decimal/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `image_path` column has a `default` keyword without any value, which, as you've seen, is wrong.

However, `text` columns can't have default values anyway, so you should just drop this keyword. When you try to insert a row into this table you'll have to supply an `image_path` value, or the insert statement will fail with an error:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `product_list` (
  `id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `image_path` text NOT NULL, -- Note that the "default" keyword was removed
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `delete_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```